# What are the excited states of electrons in an atom?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I am a sophomore and still taking modern physics.
I am having some trouble understanding what we mean by excited states of electrons in an atom in the introductory level of quantum physics.

I keep imagining the Bohr model and still can not get rid of classical mechanics.

So how can I imagine these excited states?

Comment: There is some specificity issue because the term "excited states" is used in multiple senses to mean different things. I think you are probably thinking about excited states of hadrons, but it isn't clear from the question.

Comment: Do you mean excited states _of electrons in an atom_?  If so, please _edit your question_ for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question I will use a specific example. Consider the hydrogen atom (1 electron). When we solve for the quantum mechanical wave equations we find that the following energy eigenvalues are possible (these are the possible physical measurable values of the energies): $E_n \sim 1/n^2$ where $n\in \mathbb N_{> 0}$.
The ground states corresponds to $n=1$, larger values of n correspond to the so called excited states.
Note that larger values of n result in larger (less negative) energies. We always have negative energies for the electron since our system is bounded.
To conclude, we see that the 'distance' between excited states becomes less as n becomes larger because of the $\sim 1/n^2$  dependence.

In this framework we can imagine the ground state as a state of minimal energy and an excited state as those with higher energies (again, less negative). The hydrogen atom thus needs an external (energy) 'push' (for example via a photon of light) for the electron to move to an excited state.